# Is there an Dzogchen monastery in Canada with a accomplished lineage?

Tags: dzogchen

I am looking to learn and get initiation into Dzogchen eventually leading into Tögal and trekchö. Coming from a Indian yogic tradition the rainbow body of perfection is the pinnacle of yogic achievement. I would consider it an honour to get initiated under a master in an accomplished lineage for this purpose alone.

Also any good books that discuss the rainbow body and the dzogchen practices such as chord, trechko and togal will be immensely useful. Please give me suggestions.

Respectfully,
B

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if this monastery is a Dzogchen monastery, but you can try the [Thrangu Monastery](https://thrangumonastery.org/the-monastery/monastery-i/) in British Columbia, Canada.

This monastery belongs to the Kagyu lineage.

You can find a list of teachers [here](https://thrangumonastery.org/teachers/).

This wikipedia page on [Thrangu Rinpoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrangu_Rinpoche) states that he trained Dzogchen Ponlop Rinpoche.

Answer (score 0):

Dzogchen is a teaching of the Nyingma school, so if I were you I would begin my search at Nyingma meditation centers, for example in Vancouver there's one called The Lotus Speech belonging to Northern Treasures Nyingma Lineage. They might know where to go next.

Kagyu lineage also has great teachers and they often have "double major" in Nyingma practices but not to the point of teaching Dzogchen, I don't think so. They do teach Mahamudra though which is similar enough that you could start there and eventually transfer to Nyingma.

What you are asking for is a very advanced teaching so be prepared for a long and arduous journey going through multiple intermediate stations.